# Replacing Xml (SQL REPLACE) not affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with xml field xValue

Here is an example of xValue:

```
<EP><P ID="Expy_ServiceType" Value="box" /><P ID="Expy_ServiceName" Value="Expy Box" /><P ID="Expy_HasBranches" Value="True" /><P ID="ExpyType_Code" Value="BOX" /></EP>
```

I created update but value is not replaced.

```
UPDATE temp_tab
    SET xValue = REPLACE(CAST(xValue AS varchar(max)), 
        '<P ID="ExpyType_Code" Value="BOX" />', '<P ID="ExpyType_Code" Value="NEW_BOX" />')
    WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when your `xml` value is cast to `varchar` it removes any spaces before closing tags, so you need to do the same for your replace:

```
REPLACE(CAST(xValue AS varchar(max)), 
  '<P ID="ExpyType_Code" Value="BOX"/>', '<P ID="ExpyType_Code" Value="NEW_BOX"/>')
```

See [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1a8004c63c99654c5bbbbf7ff448efe)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would not use `REPLACE` on XML in the first place. SQL Server has good XQuery capabilities, and you can replace a single node of XML using the special `UPDATE ... SET ... .modify` syntax

```sql
UPDATE temp_tab
SET xValue.modify('
    replace value of
    (/EP/P[@ID = "ExpyType_Code"]/@Value[. = "BOX"])[1]
    with
      "NEW_BOX"
  ')
WHERE ID = 1
  AND xValue.exist('/EP/P[@ID = "ExpyType_Code"]/@Value[. = "BOX"]') = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bda015332750a7a147f0699820d3d6b)

The final `exist` clause is only necessary if you want to check if the old value actually exists before attempting to modify it.